# Recursive function in Java

Tags: java, recursion

I don't know what is wrong, please advice.

Write a recursive function `int ones(int x)`,
that returns the number of ones in the binary representation of x. Make your function work independent of the size of an int (16, 32, 64 bits).

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Recursion1 {

    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the desired binary number: ");
        int input = sc.nextInt();
        int ones(int x) {
            int count = 0;
            while(x!=0) {
                if(x==1)
                    count++;
                System.out.println("Number of ones is : "+ count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See this question, is quite similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199984/basic-java-recursion-method

Comment: @Andreas: Well...there's **one**... :-)

Comment: Note how your `ones` function is embedded inside `main`. Java does not allow that.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Ok, ok, you're right, but `main` doesn't really count. Would be interesting to see a recursive `main` though.

Comment: @Andreas: :-) I did it once (adjusting the args), then said "Don't be silly Teej" and made it its own function.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight so the recursion function shouldnt be inside the main?

Comment: Recursive method must be defined outside `main`, and it should actually be recursive (yours isn't). Then `main` should call your method.

Comment: @TheSavvyGirl You can't have methods inside methods. Move the `ones` method down after the `main` method.

Comment: Also make sure your recursion ends, or you will and up in the exception of this website..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic Java Recursion Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199984/basic-java-recursion-method)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other people pointed out your mistake and gave some ideas. I just wanted to give another solution with bit operation.

```
public class MyClass {

    public static int ones(int x) {
        if (x <= 1) return x;

        return x % 2 + ones(x >> 1);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x = 63;

        System.out.println("Ones in " + x + " : " + ones(x));
    }
}
```

Prints out `6`

Answer (score 0):

The `ones` method must be outside `main`. Then it must call itself (a recursive function, by definition, calls itself).

It receives a `String` (a text), then it checks if the first character is 1. Then it sums this value to `ones(rest of the string)`, where "rest of the string" is all the characters but the first. In the end, you count all of them, recursivelly.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the desired binary number: ");
    String input = sc.next();

    System.out.println("Number of ones is: " + ones(input));
}

static int ones(String x) {
    // check if first character is 1 or zero
    char c = x.charAt(0);
    int count = c == '1' ? 1 : 0;

    // if it's the only character, return the resulst
    if (x.length() == 1) {
        return count;
    }

    // if there are more characters, call ones(rest of the string)
    return count + ones(x.substring(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an incongruity in your problem statement, your function `int ones(int x)` doesn't work with "independent of the size of an int (16, 32, 64 bits)". A java `int` is 32 bits, so to handle ints bigger than that, you'll need to use either String or BigInteger. I have provided a case below for BigInteger. Also in your problem statement, you are to accept an integer, not a binary representation of an integer, and your function is to take this integer and not the binary representation.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinaryCounter {
    private static BigInteger one = new BigInteger("1");
    private static BigInteger two = new BigInteger("2");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter the desired INTEGER: ");
        BigInteger input = sc.nextBigInteger();

        System.out.println("Number of ones is: " + ones(input));
    }

    // x has to be a String or BigInteger to handle numbers larger than 32 bits
    static int ones(BigInteger x) {
        // eventually when we get to the end, we have to stop the recursion
        if (x.compareTo(one) == 0) { return 1; }

        int remainder = x.mod(two).intValue();
        BigInteger half = x.divide(two);

        return remainder + ones(half);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For recursion you need to call the same function itself until it reaches a certain condition. A popular example of recursion is as below:

```
public static long factorial(int n) { 
    if (n == 1) {
        return 1; 
    }
    return n * factorial(n-1); 
}
```

Please note here how the function `factorial( int n)` calls itself until `n` decreases to `1`.

Comment: What does this answer have to do with OP's question, apart from being a common example of recursion?

Comment: She's just confused on what recursion is so provided her a simple example. Should I not be doing such?