# How to make a recursive method?

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to make this recursive method.

```
public int addWithFactors(int[] a, int n) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum = sum + (i + 1) * a[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I have tried to make an if statement instead of a for loop:

```
if (n == 0) {...}
```

but I don't know what is the recursive equivalent

Comment: To use a recursive method you have to call addWithFactors within it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Basic Java Recursion Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9199984/basic-java-recursion-method)

Comment: `public static int addWithFactors(int[] a, int i) {
    return i < a.length ? a[i] * (i + 1) + addWithFactors(a, i + 1) : 0;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider this code as its recursive equivalent. In your original code, you set `a` as a given array, and `n` as the maximum term, which is at most `a.length - 1`, and `i` as the current term. Your program is effectively a summation program.

The recursive helper version is shown below, and it also handles exceptional situations such as `i` being out of bounds:

```
public int addWithFactorsRecursive(int[] a, int i, int n) {
    if (i < 0) // Exceptional case where 
        return -1;
    else if (i == n - 1) // End recursion here 
        return (i + 1) * a[i];
    else if (i < n - 1) // Return the term, and consider further terms
        return (i + 1) * a[i] + addWithFactorsRecursive(a, i + 1, n);
    return 0;
}
```

The outputs I will show to you will take an array input `a`, and loop `addWithFactors(a, 0)` to `addWithFactors(a,a.length)`.

Here is one input I used, `{1,4,9,16}` and the output I got, the one on the left being your current iterative version, and the one on the right being the recursive version:

```
0 1 // n == 0 
1 1 // n == 1 
9 9 // n == 2 
36 36 // n == 3
```

Similarly for `{2,4,8,16,32,64}`, I got

```
0 2
2 2
10 10
34 34
98 98
258 258
```

Answer (score 0):

you can define your function like this:

```
public int addWithFactors(int[] a, int n) {
     if (n == 1)
            return a[n - 1];
     return (n) * a[n - 1] + addWithFactors(a, n - 1);
}
```

You shuld call it like below:

```
    addWithFactors(new int[] {1, 1, 2} ,3)
```

And it return 9.

Answer (score -1):

```
private int addWithFactorsInternal(int[] a, int n, int i) {
   if (i == n) {
      return 0; //base case
   }
   return addWithFactors(a, n, i + 1) + (i + 1) * a[i];
}
```

`addWithFactors(a, n, i + 1)` makes recursive calls incrementing `i`. The base case is when `i` reaches `n` where you return 0.

For others, you add `(i + 1) * a[i]` to the recursive call and return.

If your top-level method is of the signature you've mentioned, you can call the above as

```
public int addWithFactors(int[] a, int n) {
     return addWithFactorsInternal(a, n, 0);
}
```

**NOTE:** I didn't assume `n` is equal to `a.length`

*Example:*

`a = {1,4 5}` `n = 3` (Read the LHS from top to bottom and RHS from bottom to top)

[Returns 24]

```
addWithFactorsInternal(a, 3, 0) - 23 + (0 + 1) * 1 = 24
addWithFactorsInternal(a, 3, 1) - 15 + (1 + 1) * 4 = 23
addWithFactorsInternal(a, 3, 2) - 0 + (2 + 1) * 5 = 15
addWithFactorsInternal(a, 3, 3) - returns 0 (base case)
```